# How to hide particular listitems that are used for making a menu for particular users?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a list view which is used for making a menu in master page and when an user login to master page some list item should be made hidden or set visibility as false. I have attached my list items below. Suggest me some solution.

```
<div id="cssmenu">
    <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="HomePage.aspx"><span>HOME</span></a></li>
        <li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><span>MASTER</span></a>
        <ul>
            <li> <a href="InsDet.aspx"><span>INS MASTER</span></a></li>
            <li> <a href="OperDet.aspx"><span>OPER MASTER</span> </a></li>
            <li> <a href="EmployDet.aspx"><span>EMPLOY MASTER</span></a></li>
            <li class="last"><a href="LoginDet.aspx"><span>LOGIN DETAILS</span></a> </li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="Allot.aspx"><span>NEW CAR</span></a> </li>
        <li><a href="Progress.aspx"><span>PROGRESS</span></a></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

I need to hide Oper Master and Employ Master from my list when a particular employee login and those should be visible when admin login into it.

Comment: What have you tried? If I have something like this I check the user in my codebehind and render the menu according to the user and place it on the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give you a start where you can add the rest:

```
// Get employee from Session
Employee employee = (Employee)Session["Employee"];

// Check if employee exists
if(employee != null)
{
    RenderMenu(employee);
}

// Method to render list
private void RenderMenu(Employee employee)
{
    StringBuilder _menu = new StringBuilder();
    _menu.Append("<ul>");

    // Property boolean that indicates if the employee is an admin
    if(employee.IsAdmin)
    {
        //Add items for admin
    } 

    _menu.Append("</ul>");

    // Panel on the aspx page where you add the menu control
    this.pnlMenu.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl() { Text = _menu.ToString() });
}
```